How to retrieve current state of my state machine using boost::statechart::asynchronous_state_machine
I have created an asynchronous state machine by following the boost tutorial available at: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/statechart/doc/tutorial.html#AsynchronousStateMachines
As follows:
#include <boost/statechart/event.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/state.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/asynchronous_state_machine.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

namespace sc = boost::statechart;

struct Start;


struct MyMachine : sc::asynchronous_state_machine<MyMachine, Start>
{
  MyMachine (my_context ctx) : my_base(ctx)
  {

  }

};

struct Start : sc::state<Start,MyMachine>
{
  using my_base::my_base;

  // here implemented the react method
};

struct StartEvent: boost::statechart::event<StartEvent>
{
};

struct MyCustomEvent: boost::statechart::event<MyCustomEvent>
{
};

struct StopEvent: boost::statechart::event<StopEvent>
{
};

and the main.cpp contains:
int main()
{
    sc::fifo_scheduler<> scheduler( true );

    // Each player is serviced by its own scheduler
    sc::fifo_scheduler<>::processor_handle machineHandle = 
    scheduler.create_processor< MyMachine >();
    scheduler.initiate_processor( machineHandle );

    // the initial event that will start
    boost::intrusive_ptr<StartEvent> startEventPtr =
    new StartEvent();

    scheduler.queue_event(machineHandle, startEventPtr );

    // Run scheduler in a new thread
    boost::thread threadProcessor( boost::bind( &sc::fifo_scheduler<>::operator(), &scheduler, 0 ) );

    boost::intrusive_ptr<MyCustomEvent> customEventPtr = new MyCustomEvent();

    scheduler.queue_event(machineHandle, customEventPtr );


// here i need to retrieve the actual state of MyMachine state machine or wait for a state change



    return 0;
}


How I can retrieve the actual state of MyMachine state machine?
With a synchronous state machine there is a state_cast method of boost::statechart::state_machine does something exists on the async one?
Thanks for your help.

The class boost::statechart::asynchronous_state_machine inherit from state_machine which has the implementation of state_cast
As for now I only found this solution that implies casting sc::fifo_scheduler<>::processor_handle to my own class MyMachine:
const Start *actualState = dynamic_cast<MyMachine *>(machineHandle.lock()->get())->state_cast<const Start *>();

if (actualState != nullptr)
{
  std::cout << "The state machine is on start state" << std::endl;
}

